# Iniciar cronómetro a partir de hora dada extraida de base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html5, mysqli

Tengo una sección de monitoreo en tiempo real en mi sistema de tickets.

Esta sección en cuestión consiste en una pequeña tabla que imprime el número del ticket, el técnico al que se le asignó, el tiempo de respuesta y la hora en la que se creó el ticket.

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table m-0">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th># Ticket</th>
        <th>Technician</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Time elapsed from assigned time</th>
        <th>Assigned Time</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <?php
          $tickets = array();{
              $tickets = TicketData::getAllToDo();              
          }
          if (count($tickets) > 0) {
              // if there are tickets opened
          ?>
       <?php
          foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
             $project = $ticket->getProject();
             $events = TicketData::getEvents();
          ?>
       <?php $ticketStatus = $ticket->getStatus()->name; ?>
       <tr>
         <td><a href="index.php?view=viewticket&id=<?php echo$ticket->id; ?>"><?php $ticketId=$ticket->id; echo $ticketId; ?></a></td>
         <td><?php echo $ticket->getUser()->name." ".$ticket->getUser()->lastname; ?></td>
         <td>
          <?php if($ticketStatus=="In Process"){
          echo "<span class='badge badge-warning'>".$ticketStatus."</span>";
          }elseif ($ticketStatus=="Pending") {
             echo "<span class='badge badge-danger'>".$ticketStatus."</span>";
          }
          ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php
            $newCon = new Database();
            $con = $newCon->connect();
            $assignedToTecnico = "SELECT id, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,convert(time_at,time),convert(visit_hour_in, time))) as tiempo, (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,convert(time_at,time),convert(visit_hour_in, time))/COUNT(tecnico_id)) as average FROM ticket where id=".$ticketId;
            $query = $con->query($assignedToTecnico);   
            $row = $query->fetch_row();
            $time= $row[2];
            $timesec= ($time)*60;
            $days = floor($timesec / (60 * 60 * 24));
            $timesec -= $days * (60 * 60 * 24);
            $hours = floor($timesec / (60 * 60));
            $timesec -= $hours * (60 * 60);
            $minutes = floor($timesec / 60);
            $timesec -= $minutes * 60;
            $seconds = floor($timesec);
            $timesec -= $seconds;
            if ($days==0 && $hours==0 && $minutes==0) {
               echo "The technician hasn't visited the client yet.";
            }else{ 
               echo "{$days} days, {$hours} hours, {$minutes} minutes.";
            }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <?php echo$ticket->time_at; ?>
        </td>
       </tr>
       <?php } ?>
       <?php
          } else {
              echo "<p class='alert alert-danger'>No hay tickets abiertos</p>";
          }
       ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solo es una tabla estática y mi código ya imprime el tiempo que ha pasado dede que el ticket se abrió. Sin embargo, estaba considerando la posibilidad de mostrarlo *en tiempo real*, hacer que corra un cronómetro hasta que `visit_hour_in`, el campo de la base de datos en el que se guarda la hora de entrada del técnico, se llene. Todo esto para evitar que apareza el texto *"El técnico aún no visita al cliente".*

Vi [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26050234/11085376) a una situación similar, y [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625957/date-from-mysql-db-to-javascript-timer) con un problema similar al mío.

Probé con lo último, sin embargo obtengo un error en la consola de errores, que dice

> NaN

¿Como puedo lograr lo que requiero, con Javascript?